How can I install pipelines library without dependency error
I got an error. Please Help me.
I want to install pipelines library and you know, this requires pyyaml.
But PYYAML is already installed in my platform with py3.10(I can't change py version).
Building wheels for collected packages: pyyaml
Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─\> \[682 lines of output\]
In file included from ext/\_yaml.c:343:
ext/\_yaml.h:10: warning: "PyString_CheckExact" redefined
...

ext/\_yaml.c:20867:13: error: 'PyThreadState' {aka 'struct \_ts'} has no member named 'exc_traceback'; did you mean 'curexc_traceback'?
20867 |     tstate-\>exc_traceback = local_tb;
|             ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
|             curexc_traceback
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
\[end of output\]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyyaml
Running setup.py clean for pyyaml
Failed to build pyyaml
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyyaml, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


Are you sure that you wanted pipelines a pypi project with no description and no other website with information about it that is (see phd's answer) abandoned and old? Double check (or link here) where you found a reference to pipelines. Good chance a different python package or functionality of one was referenced

pipelines, the current latest version 0.0.14 was released in 2017. The homepage getpipelines.com redirects to a personal (author's?) blog which also was last updated in 2017. The project seems to be outdated and abandoned.
It requires PyYAML 3.11 which was released in 2014. Very old, the current version is 6. It declares compatibility with Python 2 (2.5-2.7) and 3 (3.0-3.2).
The bottom line is: the project is old and cannot be used with modern versions of Python. Try older Pythons: 3.8, 3.6, 2.7.

Thanks for your answer. You're right, But I can't try older version. I use specific notebook environment and I can't change py version.

@RichardLevinson Then you cannot install pipelines, sorry. Try to find more modern libraries.
